# Message Flashing flask

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask web app set up and currently my code has been set up so that when users sign up their details are saved to a database, set up using SQLite and SQLAlchemy. At the moment when the new user is created — it returns `return '<h1>New user has been created!</h1>'` on a new page, but I'm looking to get it to display on the same html page.

I have looked at examples of message flashing online and Stack Overflow, but not sure how to set it up with the way my code is set up. I have included the signup and login sections in `app.py` file and `signup.html` template to reproduce the problem.

### Signup section in app.py file

```
@app.route('/signup/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = RegisterForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return '<h1>New user has been created!</h1>'

    return render_template('signup.html', form=form, errors=form.errors.items())
```

### signup.html Template

```
{% block body_content %}
<div class="container">

<form method="POST" action="/signup">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="form-group">
       {{ form.username }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.email }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.password }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
    </form>

      <div class="errors">
        {% for field, err in errors %}
            <p>{{field}} : {{err|join(', ')}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
</div> 
{% endblock %}
```

### Login section of app.py File

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

        flash("Invalid username or password")

    return render_template('login.html', form=form, errors=form.errors.items())
```

Comment: You could try `return redirect(url_for('signup', msg='New user has been created!'))` then in your template just display the `msg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in your html:

```
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
      <div class=flash>{{ message }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And this in your py:

```
from flask import flash
```

and instead of

```
return "<h1>...
```

Put this:

```
flash("some text to flash")
```

Comment: Thanks that worked . When i try do it for my login it does't seem to work. I have added the code to my original question

Comment: @JoM you need to put the `flash(...)` before the `return redirect(...)`

Comment: That still doesn't work I still get the error "flask.debughelpers.FormDataRoutingRedirect"

Comment: @kstullich  
flask.debughelpers.FormDataRoutingRedirect FormDataRoutingRedirect: A request was sent to this URL (localhost:5000/login) but a redirect was issued automatically by the routing system to "localhost:5000/login/";. The URL was defined with a trailing slash so Flask will automatically redirect to the URL with the trailing slash if it was accessed without one. Make sure to directly send your POST-request to this URL since we can't make browsers or HTTP clients redirect with form data reliably or without user interaction.

Comment: @JoM `action={{ url_for('signup') }}`

Comment: From what I understand, you don't want to redirect at all, when the info provided by user is wrong. Then you will need to do something with javascript instead of flash.